# Convert a hexadecimal string array to int values

Tags: java, arrays, file, hex

I'm pretty new to java and I am trying to to convert this string array with hexadecimal values into an int array. I have no clue how to do it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class cruzD_OSpgm2
{

    public static void fileReader()
    {
        ArrayList<String> ramChipList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try 
        {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
               FileReader("RAMerrors"));
           String sCurrentLine;
           while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)
           {
               ramChipList.add(sCurrentLine);
           }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        String[] ramChip = new String[ramChipList.size()];
        ramChip = ramChipList.toArray(ramChip);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        fileReader();
    }
}
```

here are the 4 hex values 
ABCDEFABC
1A00D0000
7A0EDF301
3CDAEFFAD

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Integer.parseInt("Array as a string", 16)

Answer (score -1):

`new java.math.BigInteger("ABCDEFABC",16);`

@See JavaDoc:

- [BigInteger(String value, int radix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score -1):

All integer, Long, BigInteger classes have parse method which take string as input and convert it to value. Check Integer documentation 
[java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))